# Dinamically hide parts of html in webview

Tags: javascript, ios, css, swift

I'm working on a proof of concept feature to add the ability to hide part of a web page loaded in a webview, and I can't get it working...

I have something like this in a UIWebview extension, calling it when the webview finishes loading:

```
    let dummyStyle = "var dummyStyle = document.createElement('style'); dummyStyle.innerHTML = 'div {display: none;}'; document.body.appendChild(dummyStyle); "

    let classToHide = "content"
    let jsHideString = "var e = document.body.getElementByClassName('\(classToHide)'); e.style = dummyStyle; e.style.display = 'none';"
    self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(dummyStyle + jsHideString)
```

The main issue seems to be (checked with safari/chrome developer tools) that the document element doesn't have a style property. Even if I set it manually in the console, it doesn't update when e.style.display = 'none'.

Besides searching for the element id or class, I want to keep the assumptions about the end user web page to a minimum.

Thanks for reading my question!

**Edit with working solution:**

```
    let classToHide = "content"
    let jsHideString = " " +
        " var e = document.body.getElementsByClassName(\"\(classToHide)\")[0];" +
        "e.style.display = \"none\";"

    let DOMContentLoadedNotification = " " +
        "var addL = function addListener(obj, eventName, listener) { " +
            "if (obj.addEventListener) { " +
            "alert('added listener');" +
            "obj.addEventListener(eventName, listener, false); " +
            "} else { " +
            "alert('attactch event');" +
            "obj.attachEvent(\"on\" + eventName, listener); " +
            "};" +
            "};" +

        "var completion = function finishedDCL() { " +
            "alert('finishedDCL');" +
            jsHideString +
            "};" +

        "if (document.readyState == \"complete\" || document.readyState == \"loaded\") { " +
                "alert('document already loaded');" +
                jsHideString +
            "} else {" +
                "alert('document not loaded');" +
                "addL(document, \"DOMContentLoaded\", completion()); " +
"};"

    print("Webview: \(self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(DOMContentLoadedNotification))")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't generate the stylesheet, just manipulate directly the `.style` property of the DOM node.

Set `nodeReference.style.display = 'none'`

The problem with no style property must be that you don't wait for the DOM to be ready. Watch for the DOMContentLoaded event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Thanks for the info!